# Start Function if input length > 3 characters

Tags: jquery

**Part 1:** I want the `.highlight()` function to be active only when the input length is larger than 3. After 3 characters, I want every keystroke to look for this value and apply the `.highlight()` function (which works fine when using a static value). I am using it as a find in page function.

So here's what I have tried, but without success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  if($("#search_doc_input").length > 3) {
    $('#search_doc_input').keydown(function() {
      $(body).highlight($(this).val()); 
    });
  }
});

</script>
```

**Part 2:** Also, what would be the best way, once the highlight function is active for a certain value, to scroll to the first instance of the new `<span class="highlight">` added (which is what the .highlight() function does)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/uZVGb/1/

Updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/8aM2d/1/

Comment: This works great, but it stops at 4 characters! Any character inputed after doesn'T work... should this be enclosed in a loop? How would you see this? Thanks!

Comment: On a side note, the scrollTo doesn'T work, the console shows a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
"

Comment: Hi, I just tried in FF7/mac, Safari5/mac, Opera/mac, IE6, and it worked without error (after removing console.logs).

Comment: OK, so here's the thing. First it stops after 4 characters, so no matter what you do after it doesn't work. I updated your jsfiddle, if you type in hell, you'll scroll down to the first one. If you continue to HellY, it doesn't scroll. Is there a loop there that would start the script everytime a new key is added or removed? http://jsfiddle.net/8aM2d/

Comment: Also, the scrolling part works in your example, but since the class is added with the .highlight(), I guess the script doesn't see it on page load. What do you think?

Comment: I made a working example using http://bartaz.github.com/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html , the fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/8aM2d/1/ . $(window).load doesn't seem to work in the fiddle, so I also initialize the highlighting at $(doc).ready(). I gave an initial value to the search field too.

Answer (score 4):

`if($("#search_doc_input").length > 3)` will actually check if there is more than 3 dom elements that match your selector, wich is an id, so that should never happen.

You probably want to look at the length of the value that's in the input, like this :

```
if($("#search_doc_input").val().length > 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the length check should be done within keydown before calling highlight.

The way you have it currently keydown won't be hooked up if length is less than 3. Which is probably true when you load the page

Comment: if I use a default value (for the input box) of a length > 3, it still doesn't start the function...

Comment: Did you mean to do $('body') instead of $(body)?   Also I would test if $('body').highlight('foo') first to see if the highlight plugin is doing its job ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your all logic in the `keyup` event handler.

To also check on page load, call `keyup()` after adding the handler to run it immediately.